# Perl: open3 but for n file descriptors

Tags: perl, ipc, pid

open3 only takes STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. If the command being run uses other file descriptors then open3 cannot capture those:

```
echo foo # Can be captured
echo foo >&2 # Can be catured
echo foo >&3 # Cannot be captured (with open3)
```

I have looked into IPC::Run::run which seems to be able to deal with that, but I also need the PID and I found no way for IPC::Run::run to give me that.

Is there an openN or a way for IPC::Run::run to give me the PID?

**Background**

This is intended for a possible extension of GNU Parallel, so you can do:

```
parallel 'echo {} start >&3;sleep 10;echo {} end >&3' ::: a b c 3>out.file
```

without having the output from different jobs mixed. GNU Parallel needs to keep track of each pid - especially when `--keep-order` is used.

Comment: Why do you want the pid?

Comment: IPC::Open3 doesn't stop you from putting a pipe on fd3. It just won't do it for you.

Comment: The child's pid is known in the IPC::Run internals. Just replace `IPC::Run::run` by `IPC::Run::start` and dump the returned object. Unfortunately this is not documented, so you're on your own...

Comment: @ikegami If you post an answer with `echo {} start >&3;sleep 10;echo {} end >&3` as the command being run and fd3 assigned to a perl file handle, I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

fd3 will already exist, so all you need to do is make sure the children inherit it. Since it's inherited itself, you shouldn't have to do anything at all.

```
$ perl -e'
   system "echo foo >&3";
' 3>bar

$ cat bar
foo
```

But if you want to make sure it's inherited, you can use the following

```
$ perl -e'
   use Fcntl qw( F_GETFD F_SETFD FD_CLOEXEC );
   if (open(my $fh, ">&=", 3)) {
      my $flags = fcntl($fh, F_GETFD, 0)
         or die $!;
      fcntl($fh, F_SETFD, $flags & ~FD_CLOEXEC)
         or die $!;
   }

   system "echo foo >&3";
' 3>bar

$ cat bar
foo
```

Comment: I do not want it inherited. I want to take all that the child prints on fd3 put in a file, and when child dies, print the file on fd3. I know how to do the last part (printing when child dies).

Comment: Keep in mind that in GNU Parallel I can have multiple children writing to each their fd3 at the same time, and I do not want the output mixed, so GNU Parallel needs to capture the output before it reaches the fd3 of GNU Parallel.

Comment: If you can make open4(fd0,fd1,fd2,fd3,cmd,arg) and base it on open3 then that will be fine, too.