# Can GNU Parallel also group output of other file descriptors other than stdout and stderr?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a simple bash script `curlit.sh` (simplified):

```bash
# stdout and stderr are used for other output
echo "hello"
>&2 echo "world"
# curl outputs result and headers respectively to fd 3 and 4
curl --output > >(cat >&3) --dump-header > >(cat >&4) "$1"
```

Now if I parallelize my script with millions of domain names:

```
cat MillionDomains.out |
  parallel -j0 ./curlit.sh {} > stdout.out 2> stderr.out 3> html.out 4> header.out
```

parallel groups `stdout.out` and `stderr.out` but the output for `html.out` and `header.out` is interleaved and basically useless.

**Can I configure parallel to also group output from fd 3 and 4, \ie buffer it and print it per process?**

Comment: I suppose @ole-tange is the best candidate to answer this!

Comment: I've never tried it, but maybe you could send fd 3 and 4 to a little **Redis** instance using `redis-cli` to append to an *"in-memory"* Redis list named according to the **GNU Parallel** job number. It's just a high-performance in-memory data structure server.

Comment: @MarkSetchell each script should then write directly to redis? It might work, but I'd rather avoid just another dependency. I could also mount an in memory file system and write there for the sake of speed. But I hope that parallel has a solution for me!

Comment: It was just a thought... while waiting for Ole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently GNU Parallel cannot do that.

I tried autodetecting which file descriptor were open, and buffer those.

Detection is pretty much just:

```
for $fd (1..255) {
    open($fd{$fd}, ">&=$fd") || delete $fd{$fd};
}
```

But I use open3 to run the jobs and do the redirection. If you can show how to make an openN (as opposed to open3), then I am open to building that.

[Perl: open3 but for n file descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659956/perl-open3-but-for-n-file-descriptors)